# Automapper, MapFrom and EF dynamic proxies

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have been trying to map my domain objects to a report view model. Things all worked well in testing where I faked the entity framework code out and used a builder to return a fully populated pocco object.  Now that I am actually hitting the database and returning data I am seeing some wierd dynamic proxy type errors.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
public class ContactMapping  : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ReportRowModel>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.Gender, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Gender.Name));

    }

}
```

And the mapping code is like this:

```
var contact = GetContactFor(clientPolicy);
Mapper.DynamicMap(contact, rowModel);
return rowModel;
```

The contact fields all populate correctly except for the `rowModel.Gender` field which is returning System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Gender_3419AAE86B58120AA2983DA212CFFEC4E42296DA14DE0836B3E25D7C6252EF18

I have seen solutions where people have had problems using Map instead of DynamicMap, but I haven't found anything where a .ForMember mapping is failing like this.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Does `DynamicMap` use profiles?

Comment: I am new to Automapper so I am not sure.  I guess it does as the rest of the properties on contact populate as expected

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think DynamicMap would work regardless. Have you tried just regular `Map()`?

Comment: Yes I get a "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping" exception

Comment: You were definitely on the right track. Once I had the AutoMapperConfigurator.Configure() method being called all was good.

Comment: Did you end up using `Map` or `DynampicMap`? Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your EF query is not returning the Gender, it is returning a Proxy that can get Gender for you when evaluated, which is not of the type that AutoMapper built a mapping to handle.

You either need to eagerly fetch Gender in your query, or use [AutoMapper's IQueryable Extention](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions)'s Project method to have AutoMapper emit an anonymous projection (again, in your query), rather than try to apply the AutoMapping after the result has been returned from your EF context.

This is good practice in general to avoid Select N+1 issues.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I accepted this as the answer, but in the end it turned out to be a simple mistake on my behalf.  I created a Bootstrap method with the AutoMapperConfigurator.Configure() in it and just forgot to call the method in my code. :(

Comment: Ah. That would do it too. Generally Automapper handles child classes just fine, I figured you had something in your code preventing that. Either way, it's better to map inside your query method and return the desired type rather than on the classes returned from your query method.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue right now with version 4.x, reverting to 3.3.1 fixed the issue.