# AutoMapper with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I am using [AutoMapper v6.1.1](http://automapper.org/) with [EntityFramework v6.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) when I try to map my EF Entities and try to convert it to the DTO's I am getting following error:

```
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507228/automapper-mapfrom-and-ef-dynamic-proxies) but didn't helped me. This is something to do with EF dynamic proxy have different type. Something like this:

*System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Gender_3419AAE86B58120AA2983DA212CFFEC4E42296DA14DE0836B3E25D7C6252EF18*

CODE:

```
Mapper.Initialize(c => c.CreateMap<MyEntity, MyDTO>());      


using (var context = new DbContext())
{
        var entities= context.MyTable.GetAll().ToList();
        var myDTOs = Mapper.Map<List<MyEntity>, List<MyDTO>>(entities); // <---error here
}
```

Can someone help me how to handle Entity Framework dynamic proxy with AutoMapper.

Thank you.

Comment: `var myDTOs = Mapper.Map<List<MyDTO>>(entities);`?

Comment: Doesn't work same error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do this sort of mapping on individual objects rather than lists. Try something like:

```
var myDTOs = entities.Select(e => Mapper.Map<MyEntity, MyDTO>(e)).ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't work same error: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Comment: In that case I don't think anyone can help you without knowing what you're mapping from and to and how you've configured the mapper. As I understand it, that error message is a pretty generic AutoMapper error that can be caused by a wide range of issues.